# MS Access running SQL Update Error 3464

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So I have been searching on here but can't seem to find an answer that makes my code work. I know I'm just missing something but can't figure it out.

I am Running MS Access 2013 and trying to run the follow SQL "Update" in VBA but keep getting

> runtime error 3464 : Data Type Mismatch

```vb
Function ChangeTaskRank(NewRank As Integer, PriorityLevel As Integer, UserGroup As String)

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tableDF As DAO.TableDef

Dim sqlString As String
Dim currentRank As Integer
Dim nextRank As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set tableDF = db.TableDefs("Task_List")

SelectTaskQueryDB PriorityLevel, UserGroup

currentRank = TempVars!tmp_Task_MaxRank

Do While (currentRank >= NewRank)

    nextRank = currentRank + 1

    db.Execute "UPDATE Task_List " & _
    "SET [Task_Rank]= " & nextRank & " " & _
    "WHERE (([Task_Rank] = " & currentRank & ") AND ([Task_Priority] = " & PriorityLevel & ") AND ([Task_UserGroup] = '" & UserGroup & "'));"


    'Update
    'SET Task_Rank = (currentRank + 1)
    'WHERE (([Task_Priority] = PriorityLevel) AND ([Task_UserGroup] = UserGroup));

    currentRank = currentRank - 1

Loop

End Function
```

What I am trying to do with code is run a loop that will change the Rank of a task when a new one is added (IE: you have task rank 1 to 5 and add a new task at 3, the code will change the task rank of 3,4,5 to 4,5,6.)

Database info:

```
Table name: Task_List
Field Name: Task_Rank (Integer)
```

Filters:

```
[Task_Rank] = currentRank (Integer)
[Task_Priority] = PriorityLevel (Integer)
[Task_UserGroup] = UserGroup (String)
```

Any help would be great as this is driving me nuts lol. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With debugging like this, I like to set the SQL to a String first, and then use `Debug.Print sSQL` to make sure the results make sense, then you can `db.Execute sSQL` - When you do this, what are the results?

Comment: need the code for SelectTaskQueryDB  and the line of the error

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: @brax When I run the Debug I get: UPDATE Task_List SET [Task_Rank]= 2 WHERE (([Task_Rank] = 1) AND ([Task_Priority] = 1) AND ([Task_UserGroup] = 'BIM Group')); Which has all the correct numbers and string in it.

Comment: Is your `Task_Priority` field also integer *in the database table* ?

Comment: .....Well..... I thought I had set it to integer... But now that you say that, it did not save change... Thank you very much guys. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a parameterized SQL query with a conditional `IIF` to avoid any looping, quote enclosures, and string concatenation.

**SQL** *(save as a saved query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS NewRankParam LONG, PriorityLevelParam LONG, UserGroupParam TEXT;
UPDATE Task_List  t
SET [Task_Rank]= IIF(t.[Task_Rank] >= NewRankParam, t.[Task_Rank] + 1, t.[Task_Rank])
WHERE ((t.[Task_Priority] = PriorityLevelParam) AND (t.[Task_UserGroup] = UserGroupParam));
```

**VBA**

```vb
Function ChangeTaskRank(NewRank As Integer, PriorityLevel As Integer, UserGroup As String)

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

    qdef!NewRankParam = NewRank
    qdef!PriorityLevelParam = PriorityLevel
    qdef!UserGroupParam = UserGroup

    qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

    Set db = Nothing
    Set qdef = Nothing

End Function
```